# String to Time format only ( No Date)

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a `string` whose value is **16:00:00** i want to convert it to time format hh:mm:ss.. **i dont want date**

`TimeSpan.ParseExact(splitLine[6], "hh:mm:ss", null);` is throwing error that system.time cannot be coverted to system.date time

`DateTime.ParseExact(splitLine[6], "hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`  is returning date time with adding Today's date automstically.

I just want time format.

please help me.

Comment: If you atleast once went to this site you must have came to know about it. http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-format Go there and learn the basics!

Comment: If you're willing to be a bit adventurous you can abandon the .Net standard date/time objects and go with something a lot better: Noda-Time http://nodatime.org/

Comment: Use can use DateTime.ParseExact(splitLine[6], "HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay or follow the answer by @Hamlet Hakobyan 
TimeSpan.ParseExact(splitLine[6], "T", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [Custom TimeSpan Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx) you have to escape delimiters such as colons, for example:

```
TimeSpan.ParseExact(splitLine[6], "hh':'mm':'ss", null)
```

or:

```
TimeSpan.ParseExact(splitLine[6], @"hh\:mm\:ss", null)
```

Note that this is different from `DateTime` format strings where some delimiters, like colon `:`, have a special meaning while others, like period `.`, have no meaning but don't need to be escaped.

Comment: Also remember, even if it is not needed here, that you can get rid of the date "part" of a `DateTime` by using the [`TimeOfDay` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992370.aspx):

> The ParseExact method uses the conventions of the culture specified by
>   the formatProvider parameter only if format is a standard TimeSpan
>   format string whose value is either "g" or "G". The "c", "t", and "T"
>   standard format strings use the formatting conventions of the
>   invariant culture. Custom format strings define the precise format of
>   the input string and use literal characters to separate the components
>   of a time interval.

then, you can use this to achieve your goal.

```
TimeSpan.ParseExact(splitLine[6], "T", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about below code. It's working fine for me.

```
string time = "16:00:00";
TimeSpan.Parse(time);
```

Comment: What about `TimeSpan.Parse("160:00:00")`?

Comment: OP specifically told in question that the string is 16:00:00. Thats why I added this simplest way.